# Using content_tag with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, content-tag

I'm having difficulties figuring out how to get `content_tag` to work with HAML.

Without HAML, I'd do something like this:

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "instagrams", data: { instagrams: @instagrams } do %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried the following, to no avail:

```
%div#instagrams{ instagrams: @instagrams }

%div{ id: "instagrams", data: { instagrams: @instagrams } } do

- haml_tag("div", id: "instagrams", data: { instagrams: @instagrams })
```

I've tried Google but still can not figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is this:

```
#instagrams{ data: { instagrams: @instagrams.to_json } }
```

In HAML you don't need `%div` (this is the default for a tag) so you can just put the id and you still need to define `data:` for data attributes rather than just HTML attributes.

Also, you should leave out the `do` block portion for anything that is not a ruby code execution (like `haml_tag` or a rails helper like `form_for`). In HAML white space is significant so the nested block structure is implied.

The problem with your `haml_tag` example may be that you used `-` instead of `=`. In HAML the former means execute ruby that does not return markup, while the latter should return markup.

Comment: Hey Andrew, your solution worked. Thanks so much! However, I needed it in json:

    #instagrams{ data: { instagrams: @instagrams.to_json } }

Comment: Cool. Yeah that makes since depending on what the `@instagrams` object actually is.